# jquery/jquery mobile plugin - widget - calling private method doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, methods, jquery-mobile, widget

I'm trying to call the private method _scrollMe from within my plugin, but I keep getting an error that it's not a function.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
    (function( $, window, undefined ){
      $.widget( "mobile.multiview", $.mobile.widget, {        
        _create: function() {
           this._morph();
           },
        _morph: function() {
           $('div[data-role="page"]').live('pagebeforeshow.scroll', function(event){
               var $page = $(this);
               if ( $page.data('scrollable', 'Off') ) {
                   $page._scrollMe(); // this doesn't fire 
                   }
             });
           },
       _scrollMe: function () {
           alert ("scrollMe");
           }
    }); 

// initialize
$( document ).bind( "pagecreate", function( ) {
       $(document).multiview();
       });  

})(jQuery,window);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the private method using the wrong syntax - using `$page.method` is trying to call it as a public method.

Changing it to `this._scrollMe` should work.

Comment: doesn't work. Could it be because I'm calling the plugin on window (="this") and then I'm listening for pageBeforeShow and re-using "this"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 'this' is what you expect it to be in that event callback.

Try moving the $page variable outside the function.

```
var $page = $(this);
$('div[data-role="page"]').live('pagebeforeshow.scroll', function(event){
```

and maybe this instead:

```
var $page = this;
```

// Edit //

```
_morph: function() {
    var page = this;
    $('div[data-role="page"]').live('pagebeforeshow.scroll', function(event) {
        if($page.data('scrollable', 'Off') ) {
            $page._scrollMe(); // this doesn't fire 
        }
     });
},
```

Comment: do you mean putting it after //initialize or outside of the plugin altogether?

Comment: Try putting "var $page = this" outside the live() function, but still inside the _morph one.

Comment: also doesn't do it... :-(   I still think it's cause the plugin uses this="window" and live listens for this=page. What do you think?

Comment: To be honest I haven't used $.widget() so I'm not sure exactly what it does. But since the event function is a closure, any variables put outside it should be reachable by the code inside.